# How to work several GPIO pins with shell script

Tags: gpio, pigpio, bash, pi-gpio

I realise that this is a newbie question but no where  on the internet do I find the answer.

I want to control a couple of GPIO pins on Pi (3+mod A, Buster) so I write a simple shellscript. Its using pin 7 and 12 (hardware numbering) to switch on/off a couple of relays. Approximate current use 10 mA. The idea is to switch one off when the other turns on.

```
#!/bin/bash
gpio mode 7 out
gpio mode 12 out
gpio write 7 1
gpio write 12 0
```

But no matter what I do only one pin gets turned on (7). If I switch the relays they both work but only when connected to pin 7.
I tried changing the order of the lines in script in all different combinations.

Strangely enough, when I try a script only for pin 12 it does not work either. And I have tried changing to other pins. It's like only the first number pin gets activated.

I guess there is a neat way to do this with python but this just seemed the quickest way as I am not so much at home in python.

Comment: _Strangely enough, when I try a script only for pin 12 it does not work either. And I have tried changing to other pins. It's like only the first number pin gets activated._  Those two statements are contradictory, are they not?

Comment: Yes. It's not clear here whether you mean 1) Only pin 12 does not work, 2) Only pin 7 does work, or 3) Whichever pin is mentioned 2nd in the script does not work, and whichever is mentioned first (even pin 12) always works, except when it is the only pin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default the wiringPi's `gpio` utility uses wiringPi numbering for the GPIO.

You seem to want to use physical pin numbers.

https://pinout.xyz/

Pin 7 is Broadcom GPIO 4 (wiringPi number 7).

Pin 12 is Broadcom GPIO 18 (wiringPi number 1).

So choose a numbering scheme and use the correct identifier for the GPIO and option for the `gpio` utility.

Pin numbering

```
gpio -1 mode 7 out
gpio -1 mode 12 out
gpio -1 write 7 1
gpio -1 write 12 0
```

wiringPi numbering

```
gpio mode 7 out
gpio mode 1 out
gpio write 7 1
gpio write 1 0
```

Broadcom numbering

```
gpio -g mode 4 out
gpio -g mode 18 out
gpio -g write 4 1
gpio -g write 18 0
```

Comment: @https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/users/13650/joan Thank you for taking the time to answer this!

The differnent wirining systems are complicated for a newbie, and since the BCM setup changed somewhere around pi2 it makes it hard to find examples on the web. Also there is often a term confusion regarding the actual, physical pin numbering and the wiringPi numbering.